# Exporting In-House iOS app Export button not working

Tags: ios, xcode

Exporting In-House iOS app: I am using Xcode 10.1. Export button not working, Export button is blue and highlighted. When I clicked on it and nothing is happening, beside the all provisional profiles and certificates are alright.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Please review [ask].

Answer (score 5):

Force Quit Xcode and open it again it worked for me.

Comment: Today same thing happened to me ... Xcode is worst IDE..